# Ruby - uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn ruby at the moment

I've got the below but can't figure out why i'm getting the uninitialized constant error (on `Item.new`). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

edit to clarify this is using the "Simple_form" gem. it has been bundle installed

I have it using a form as below:

```
<%= simple_form_for @item do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Item" %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

and the items controller is as below

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end

    def new
      @item = Item.new
    end

    def create

    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please check `Item.first` in your `rails console`?

Comment: Did you define `Item`? then, did you load it?

Comment: Do you have the definition for class `Item` somewhere in your code?
Like: class Item end

Comment: ashvin - is that "rails Item.first" if so it said "Don't know how to build task "Item.first" .....

Comment: it's using the simple form gem

gem 'simple_form'

have the below in a partial "_form.html.erb"

<%= simple_form_for @item do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :title, label: "Item" %>
 <%= f.input :description %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

Comment: My suggestion if you're just learning Ruby is to focus on Ruby - not Rails, not piles of other gems, just focus on the language itself.

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to create a model by name "Item"

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base 
  #Model class and object methods goes here
end
```

then only you can access values which are stored in the table my name "items" from database. 
 If you did not run the migrations use command rake db:migrate -t will create tables as you specified in the migration. After everything taken care as i specified above

go to the rails console by ruby script/console

type "Item"
and it will display the class which is associated then you can use your code.

Note: Commands which i specified will vary based on rails versions.

Comment: can you explain why it's working on the tutorial i'm following? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9GaNNztcZk&t=813s (skip to 17minutes exactly and it shows the item controller but has no class model)

Comment: Can you specify the URL which is used to access and as they specified in the video did you created new.html.erb file and there are you rendering the partial?